# How to Hide Details With a View in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my data in SQL Server 2008 R2 in a database called, say, CompanyData. I have some tables there with transaction history with a lot of details on each transaction.

For certain reporting users I want them to have reporting capacity but hiding many details.

So I went ahead and created a new database, DBReport, and created a view that selects only certain columns from the tables. For example, SELECT field1, field2, field3 from [CompanyData].[dbo].[TableA] ...

I created a new user and a new login (I confess I don't understand the difference between those, as I always create them together) called ReportingUser ONLY with db_datareader role in both DBReport.

The problem is that when I run a report as this limited user, it comes back with an error saying that under current security this ain't happening.

So my question comes down to how to I specify in the view to login to CompanyData using a valid user in CompanyData. I know I can create ReportingUser in CompanyData too, but that's precisely what I want to avoid.

I hope I'm being not so confusing here...

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, *Logins* belong to the server, *Users* belong to databases (technically, every database has its own set of users, though in practice it can well be one and the same set). It is possible to have access to the server (have a login) and have no access to a specific database (have no user in that DB associated with your login).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read about ownership chain [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) (it has a very good explanation)

I think the problem in your case is who is the owner of the objects. Probably your view on DBReport has a different owner then your [CompanyData].[dbo].[TableA] table. So you have permission on the view but it doesn't chain down to the tableA because they have different owners.

You can solve this by adding permission to the ReportUser on tableA.

About users and logins, basically logins are on a Instance Level and Users are on a database level

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, Don Diego, how do I see who owns what? And if possible, how do I change that? (Can I sell the object to a new owner:-))

Comment: Great link you gave me about ownership chain, btw.

Comment: glad to help. This proc can change the owner of an object: sp_changeobjectowner 'old_owner', 'new_owner' In your case, dbo is the owner of the TableA object

Comment: Just checked... dbo is the owner in both, but... in my original database, dbo has a 'sa' login, but in my new reporting database, dbo has a 'abc_admin' login. Is that something that can be changed (it looks grayed out) without deleting and recreating the database?

Answer (score 0):

Run up SQl Server manager connect as your limited report user
New query , paste in the sql from inside the view. see what it says.
Usual problem is references, it you have permisison to look at table2, but not table1 it has a foreign key on or similar.

Ide make sure you have select and refernces on all tables touched by the view, which would include any tables referred to by any udfs or SPs (or other views used by it).

PS does this report only use this view?